# Laravel 4: ErrorException Undefined variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

After trying for a few minutes. I have this on my routes.php file

```
Route::get('home/bookappointment/{id?}', array('as' => 'bookappointment', 'uses' => 'FrontController@getBookAppointment'));
```

And on my controller I have the following:

```
    public function getBookAppointment($id)
{
        // find all the services that are active for the especific franchise
        $activeServices = Service::whereHas('franchise', function($q) {
                $q->where('franchise_id', '=', $id);
            })->get();

        //var_dump($activeServices);die;

        return View::make('frontend/bookappointment')
                                ->with('services', $activeServices);
}
```

And I keep getting this error. 
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: undefined variables are normally ran into when a variable isn't defined.

Comment: but if I am sending this through my url ?? home/bookappointment/297

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have access to `$id` in your anonymous function. Try

```
<?php
$activeServices = Service::whereHas('franchise', function($q) use($id) {
    $q->where('franchise_id', '=', $id);
})->get();
```

Take a look at the PHP documentation for additional info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @Monica Very common problem. It happens everyday!

Answer (score 1):

The question mark after `{id` in your routes file indicates the id is optional. If it indeed should be optional, it should be defined as optional in your Controller.

Take the following example:

```
class FrontController extends BaseController {

    public function getBookAppointment($id = null)
    {
        if (!isset($id))
        {
            return Response::make('You did not pass any id');
        }
        return Response::make('You passed id ' . $id);
    }
}
```

Note how the method is defined with the `$id` argument as `= null`. This way you can allow for optional arguments.

Comment: thank you, just removed the question mark, cause I need the id.